# deregistered instance showing unreachable in mesos , how to clear this?

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesos-chronos

i am using mesos-marathon cluster for my setup and i have 40 instances registered with mesos .
i want to remove 1 instance from the cluster. To do that , i just stopped that ec2 instance and reduce the number of dns instance in marathon. But it is still showing me that 1 instance uncreachable in the cluster.
Can you help here to remove that?

[image]

image1

[image]

image2

result:  it should not show unreachable after reducing one entry from marathon

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it with:

> [`--registry_max_agent_age=VALUE`](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/master/) - Maximum length of time to store information in the registry about agents that are not currently connected to the cluster. This information allows frameworks to determine the status of unreachable and gone agents. Note that the registry always stores information on all connected agents. If there are more than `registry_max_agent_count` partitioned/gone agents, agent information may be discarded from the registry sooner than indicated by this parameter. (default: 2weeks)